# Goroutine select loop with Ticker causes CPU to 100%

Tags: go, cpu, cpu-usage, goroutine, ticker

I have this loop that what it does is trying to repeatedly poll to another server. I used ticker to achieve this however the program repeatedly shows 100% CPU usage.

This ticker runs inside a goroutine. and the HTTP server runs inside another goroutine.

```golang
func() Monitor() {

  abort := make(chan bool)

  log.Info("Monitor started.")

  // start the monitor goroutine
  go func() {
      defer log.Info("Stopped monitor")
        
      ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(35.0) * time.Second)
      defer ticker.Stop()
        
      log.Info("Monitor started! \n")
      for {
        select {
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            log.Infof("Subscribe to service at time %v\n", t)
            if err := selfConn.SubscribeToService(); err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to subscribe to primary connector: %v", err)
            } 
        case <-abort:
            log.Info("Finished routine!")
            return
        default:
            continue
        }
        }
    }() 
  
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Minute)
        abort <- true
    }()
}
```

However when monitor loops start, and everytime the signal to the ticker channel is sent, the CPU shows 100% constantly.

What have I missed in using ticker in the goroutine so that it won't consume 100% CPU?

Comment: Could you please leave a comment on why you have voted down on the question? This is my first question asked in the community, and I'm learning Go concurrency just recently. It would be helpful for me to post my next question on the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a [`select`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) with a `default` branch inside your loop. If none of the other `case`s are ready to proceed, the `default` branch is executed immediately, so your next iteration begins immediately without wait. This is a busy loop.

Also, there is no need for another goroutine to terminate, you could use a timer for that in the same goroutine.

For example:

```
func monitor() {
    log.Info("Monitor started.")

    ticker := time.NewTicker(35 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    timeoutCh := time.After(10 * time.Minute)
    for {
        select {
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            log.Infof("Subscribe to service at time %v\n", t)
            if err := selfConn.SubscribeToService(); err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to subscribe to primary connector: %v", err)
            }
        case <-timeoutCh:
            log.Info("Finished routine!")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I removed default and it is behaving much better. You are right :) I just added the termination timer for example, it should be 10mins, and the polling interval at 35s. Your example is what I am looking for :) . Thank you!